# How to continue the test even though assert fails

Tags: groovy, spock

```
@Stepwise
Class TestCaseOne extends Specification{

   def test(){
      expect:
            assert something
   }
   def testValidation(){
      expect:
            assert something
   }
   def test(){}
      expect:
            assert something
   }
   def testValidation(){
      expect:
            assert something
   }

}
```

I want testing should stop if `test` method fails but it should continue if `testValidation` method fails. Please let me know if it is possible.

I am using Groovy and spock.Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't `assert` it. just check it using `if` condition, then add text to error array and output it at the end. i.e. - `if (x.size()==0) {errorList.add("No shit created!")}`

Answer (score 1):

According to this 'issue' which covers your question https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/456 recommended way if you want to achieve full test execution is to not use @Stepwise annotation.

> robfletcher commented Aug 30, 2015
>   Just don't use `@Stepwise` then. Execution is sequential nevertheless. This might change
>   in case Spock itself ever gets some parallel execution support, but for now you'll be fine.
>   Reported by pniederw on 2013-10-24 08:47:44

Comment: If I dont use @Stepwise then all test and testValidation will be executed.no matter if any test or test validation fails. For me i want testing should stop if test method fails but it should continue if testValidation method fails.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding then, you case is more specified then. How about splitting it in two files? One for validation purposes and second test, is it possible scenario?

Comment: is it means i should create two files for validation and test and validation should  extend test and test should extend Specification. if yes then problem is after all the test executed then only validation will execute. but i  want after each test its validation should run.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible.

Either you use **@Stepwise** and it stops at the first failure. Or your don't use **@Stepwise** and it runs everything.

There is no way to mark specific methods on what should happen.

Split your test into two where one has the annotation and the other does not.